# Change header background for mobile screens only

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm trying to change the header background color for mobile screens sizes only. The below isn't working.

I'd ideally not like to change the header or header_wrap code since this is working fine. For more context, if required, I made use of this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eL1cabv9 but intentionally want the header transparent for screen sizes that are not mobile size.

Please assist. Thanks!

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .ico {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .header {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
}

.ico {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -125px;
}
.header_wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Your example and your fiddle seem pretty different. What color do you want the header to be?

Comment: I'd like it to be white (but only for below 480px). Transparent otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
header {     
    background: transparent;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
    header {
        background: #FFF;
   }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1p86ms30/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid but css won't work that way. Only the last mentioned style will apply to the element. Let me explain it clearly.

```css
.box{width: 100px; height:100px; background: red;}
.box{background: green;}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

As you can see from this sample snippet. The background color 'Green' is applied to the box element. The css simply ignored the first line where I mentioned the bg color.

The same applies here.

**your code:**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .ico {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .header {
    background: green;
  }
}

.body{margin: 0;}

.ico {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.header_wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
     <div class="header_wrap">
       <div class="ico">
         <span></span>
       </div>
     </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Fix:**

Always write media queries at the bottom of the stylesheet.

```css
.body{margin: 0;}

.ico {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.header_wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

 
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .ico {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .header {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
     <div class="header_wrap">
       <div class="ico">
         <span></span>
       </div>
     </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** Check the two snippets in responsive for better understanding.

Happy Coding!